# How to integrate Existing Java web Application to handle blogs as subdirectory

Tags: java, wordpress, blogs, subdirectory

I have a Java web application written in Spring + Hibernate + AngularJS running on Tomcat. I want to add the functionality of blog as a subdirectory. (Mostly I want to use Wordpress)

I have read many posts and googled it. But I could not find anything useful.

So basically I want my site eg -www.mysite.com to extend to www.mysite.com/blog, such that www.mysite.com will run as it is running now on TOMCAT and www.mysite.com/blog to render from Wordpress.

Please Help?

Answer (score 0):

Create a folder in your hosting space(root folder where you hosted your java application) with name "blog" and map the wordpress blog database to one newly created database, then automatically the blog will points to the www.mysite.com/blog

Better browse any search engine for more details.

Comment: I am using quercus to integrate Wordpress, as of now I am able to configure and run quercus. But still some configuration is needed in web.xml so that my domain is rendered at the specified address www.mysite.com and quercus home page under www.mysite.com/blog , as quercus is inside blog directory.